# Recognizing strings of Time in ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, time

This isn't much of a problem, really, it's entirely out of curiosity.

For a program I'm working on I write a information to files at certain times (currently once/day, may change), but it's done in such a way that the time for each recorded piece of information is important. As such, every time I want to take samples and append information to the file, first I append the following:

```
file_out.write Time.now
```

As an easy way of remembering exactly when each write was made.

Now here's what I'm curious about: is there a way to check if a string received from the file ("cur_line = file_in.gets", for example) is a Time stamp?

The reason this isn't a problem is that my current method is simple regex:

```
if cur_line =~(/^(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun) (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)/)
```

And seems to work perfectly for my needs.
(Due to the nature of the project, and the formatting of what I write, I know that there will be no other lines in the file that include any text of format '{Day} {Month}' so I stop parsing there. Just day or just month would be insufficient and lead to false positives).

Are there other, perhaps prettier, ways of checking for the timestamps? I won't necessarily use something else (especially if you say "well you can do X but it will cause performance to suffer greatly" (not that comparisons are a great concern for performance, in this project. I'd guess that the difference would probably be negligible)).

It's just something that struck me as interesting and something I guessed there might be cool ways of doing in Ruby. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do `Time.parse cur_line`, which will return the current date if the time cannot be parsed properly. Not necessarily ideal, but `Time.parse` is pretty powerful :)

EDIT: Interesting way to do your regexp:
Before you loop over the file, declare the regular expression as so:

```
expression = Regexp.new("^(#{Time::RFC2822_DAY_NAME.join("|")}) (#{Time::RFC2822_MONTH_NAME.join("|")})")
```

Then, when you loop over each line, do: `cur_line.match(expression)`. This will return `nil` if no match. An interesting (albeit longer) way to do this.

Comment: So the suggestion is that if it returns the current date (i.e. it couldn't be parsed) then I know it's wrong. So I compare what it returns to Time.now in an unless statement? 

Seems like it would add a lots of confusing code :)

Time.parse took up the majority of the subjects I found while searching this. Looks like a VERY useful tool in many cases, but here it seems a bit confusing. Definitely one to keep in mind for other situations though.

Comment: @DRobinson - probably left to cases where you are positive what you are parsing is a timestamp. I guess you could mix `Time.parse` with your regex, where the regex finds lines which are potential timestamps, and `Time.parse` is used to parse that timestamp. So, to verify, any lines which begin `{month} {day}` are guaranteed to be timestamps?

Comment: Exactly they kind of thing I was thinking it might help for. Unfortunately, so far, with this project I don't need to actually use the date in any way after I find it, I just have to toss it in an array and display it if the data it's labeling meets certain criteria (i.e. perhaps a portion of the data increases 20%, I want to just say what day the increase occurred on). Of course for this I only need a simple "puts" and don't care whether it's considered a Date or String by the computer. A wonderful tool for many situations, but not my particular one, I'm afraid :) Thank you though!

Comment: So not easier, or even shorter, but I edited my answer to include another "interesting" way to do your regexp

Answer (score 1):

You could try to run the lines through [chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/)  or [Date.parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html#M000358), but I would bet that both of these methods are less efficient than using a regular expression.  The impact of that efficiency is completely relative to how much text you have to parse.